# A JavaScript variable using a .JSON file

Tags: javascript, html

Well guys, I'm having trouble creating a function for a HTML project of mine...

```
var Pokemon = require("./json/pokemon.json");
```

The problem is, require is a node.js environment command, so how do I use a JavaScript variable to sabe de content of a JSON file without required?

Comment: Just use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)? You're in the browser: fetch your data, then do whatever you need to do with it. Having said that, why are you showing Node code if you're not working in Node?

Comment: I was transcripting a discord bot code to work in a website, discord bots works with Node.js

Comment: Then you have your answer: if you want to load "files" either load them because the browser has a built-in way to do so for you, or (in this case), load it as "a network request" using the modern Fetch API (which, in legacy times, used the XMLHttpRequest object. Don't use that anymore)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to get the JSON:

```js
fetch("YOUR-URL/json/pokemon.json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));
```